How to check whether a mesh has Custom Split Normals layer data from python API
I'm tring to get an infromation on a mesh, whether a certain mesh has Custom Split Normal Layer Data or not. I'm not sure how it's stored on the mesh data and how to access the data from python API. At the moment only way for me to know whether the mesh has the data or not is by checking the "Clear Custom Split Normals Data" button is active or not on object data properties panel's Geometry Data section.


You can query that information with has_custom_normals
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object     # get your object somehow
if obj.data.has_custom_normals:  # query it
    print('has custom split normals data') 


This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!
